# where is Kube-proxy executable on Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kube-proxy

minikube ssh

```
$ ps ax | grep kube-proxy
 4191 ?        Ssl    1:36 /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy --config=/var/lib/kube-proxy/config.conf --hostname-override=minikube
22000 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep kube-proxy



$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/kube-proxy': No such file or directory
```

This is a functional Minikube, I am able create pods, but I am not able to find Kube-proxy executable on Minikube vm.

Answer:
kube-proxy is running as Daemonset

kubectl get daemonset -n kube-system

Comment: Hi, can you run `ls -la /proc/PID/exe` as your PIS is 4191? `ls -la /proc/4191/exe`

Comment: $ sudo ls -la /proc/4191/exe 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 17 13:27 /proc/4191/exe -> /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy

Comment: run the command with sudo `sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy` ?

Comment: $ sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin/kube-proxy
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin/kube-proxy': No such file or directory

Comment: hopefully, kube-proxy is not a daemonset or itself a pod , its quite strange, need to check the docs

Comment: Thanks Suresh... yes it runs as Daemonset..

Comment: No worries Deepak, I answered the question with the generic command to list out the pods, so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kubectl get all --all-namespaces`  would list most kind of the k8s resources in all the namespaces.

**Kube-proxy** is deployed as a deamonset in the minikube.

Answer (score 3):

*Good job Suresh on figuring what this question was about. Hello on SO Deepak kumar Gunjetti in the future please try to ask concrete questions as you ask about binary and the answer is "kube-proxy is a daemonset".*

So just as an extension of the answer:
With `kubectl get all -n kube-system` you can find that kube-proxy is indeed a daemonset. [Daemonset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) is a type of object in Kubernetes that will make sure that on any node there will be one running pod of its kind.

You can also view the yaml file of kube-proxy.
Either by using `kubectl get daemonset.apps/kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml` or [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/addons/kube-proxy/kube-proxy-ds.yaml).

If you are going to look for more Kubernetes components you can find them inside of the minikube VM. You can reach them by `minikube ssh` and then navigating to Kubernetes dir `cd /etc/kubernetes` and in the folder manifests you will find the most important ones:

```
ls /etc/kubernetes/manifests/
addon-manager.yaml  etcd.yaml  kube-apiserver.yaml  kube-controller-manager.yaml  kube-scheduler.yaml
```